# how to remove coordinates from geojson with less then 4 values

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, gis

as the title say, i am doing a query on a bikesharing data stored in bigquery
I am able to extract the data and arrange it in a correct order to be displayed in a path chart. In the data, there are coordinated with only start and end long and lat, or sometimes only start long and lat, how do i remove anything with less then 4 points?
this is the code , i am also limited to select only

```
SELECT 
 routeID , 
 json_extract(st_asgeojson(st_makeline( array_agg(st_geogpoint(locs.lon, locs.lat) order by locs.date))),'$.coordinates') as geo

FROM 
 howardcounty.routebatches
where  unlockedAt between {{start_date}} and {{end_date}} 
cross join UNNEST(locations) as locs
GROUP BY routeID
order by routeID
limit 10
```

have also included a screen shot for clarity [image: coordinates screen shot]

Answer (score 1):

To apply a condition after a `group by`, please use a `having`. For a simply condition -- Are there at least two dataset for the route? -- this query can be used:

```
With dummy as (
    Select 1 as routeID,  [struct(current_timestamp() as date, 1 as lon, 2 as lat),struct(current_timestamp() as date, 3 as lon, 4 as lat)] as locations 
    Union all select 2 as routeID,  [struct(current_timestamp() as date, 10 as lon, 20 as lat)]
       )


SELECT 
 routeID , count(locs.date) as amountcoord,
 json_extract(st_asgeojson(st_makeline( array_agg(st_geogpoint(locs.lon, locs.lat) order by locs.date))),'$.coordinates') as geo

FROM 
 #howardcounty.routebatches
dummy

#where  unlockedAt between {{start_date}} and {{end_date}} 
cross join UNNEST(locations) as locs
GROUP BY routeID
having count(locs.date)>1
order by routeID
limit 10
```

For more complex ones, a nested `select` may do the job:

```
Select *
from (
 --- your code ---
) where length(geo)-length(replace(geo,"]","")) > 1+4
```

The JSON is transformed to a string in your code. If you count the `]` and substract one for the end of the JSON, the inside arrays are counted.

Comment: sorry i should have been more clear, i am limited to select only on this dataset

Comment: thanks the last part did the job  -->   where length(geo)-length(replace(geo,"]","")) > 1+4